# Deploying django project on bluehost

Tags: django, bluehost

After googling I found a working methods to deploy a project when it is located as sub-domain, e.g. http://www.example.com/myproject

But I didn't find example of deploying project on main domain.
Can somebody point me in the direction of how change htaccess and fcgi files to make project work on main domain.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this question belongs on this site...

Answer (score 0):

Try addon domain. Then add your main domain address. Rest is upon your handler (.htaccess) I am not sure this will work but I have tried this within a2hosting and this worked fine.